# store number in column field which has datatype 'integer'

Tags: php, parse-platform, numbers, type-conversion

I want store number in column field which has datatype `integer`, when I try to get the value from `$_REQUEST` variable it gives me string type so that I am having this error:

> Invalid type for key payout, expected number, but got string

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: you can try to cast it as integer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$num = $_REQUEST['your_val'];
$int = (int)$num;
$value = (float)$num
```

PHP might normally do this for you but in situations where you need to explicitly change the type, you will need to [cast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) it.

---

You can also try Use [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) or [`floatval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

```
$val = $_REQUEST['your_val'];       
$num = intval($val);
$num = floatval($val);
```

Comment: M.Doye, thanks for your reply. But when use this code.
$int = (int)$num;
it returns the integer data type, i specifically want 'number' data type.

Comment: hmm.. there is no 'number' datatype in PHP [see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php) can you provide an example of your value?